# How can you get the current recording volume reading from the microphone?

Tags: windows, microphone

How can you get the current recording volume reading from the microphone? By this, I'm referring to the loudness of the sound that is being recorded by the microphone. I've searched MSDN for hours, but to no avail... So, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think there is no simpler way than to obtain some audio using the older mixer or newer WASAPI API (i.e. start recording) and determine the volume (i.e. signal strength) yourself. For this purpose, you can easily calculate the [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), which is equal to the average signal power.

Answer (score 0):

By "Determine the volume yourself" do you mean: start recording and then use a separate thread to open the recorded file, tail it and determine the amplitude? Because that sounds fairly complicated and proc heavy - and if you don't mean that, how else to get at the recorded audio?